# Adcolony unable to find the currently visible UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ads, adcolony

I was integrating the adcolony video ads in my iphone game. When displaying the ad we are getting the error

" ADCOLONY 2.0.1 [*** ERROR ***] AdColony has ads, but could not display them. AdColony was unable to find the currently visible UIViewController for your app. Please ensure that your key UIWindow has a rootViewController."

When i checked the code in appdelegate we had already set the rootviewcontroller of UIWindow like this :

`self.viewController_ipad = [[ViewController_ipad alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] ;
        window.rootViewController = self.viewController_ipad;
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];`

Still i am getting this error. Please guide us in right direction to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I got the reply by `Adcolony` Engineers :

`AdColony` finds the visible `UIViewController` being shown in your app's key `UIWindow`, and then pushes a modal view controller, which is used to display ads, on top. Once the ad is complete, our `SDK` pops the modal view controller off, leaving your app in the state it was previously. You will encounter the error you mentioned if our `SDK` gets a nil value for your app's topmost view controller.

I can tell you that, in the past, I've seen this problem occur if a developer uses a button in an `UIAlertView` to trigger an AdColony video ad. If this is the case, and you are triggering videos from a `UIAlertView` or a `UIActionSheet`, we highly recommend making sure they are fully dismissed before you make the call to play a video.

I'd like to get this sorted out as quickly as possible for you. Is there anyway you could send us a stripped down version of your code that will reproduce the problem? If that's not a possibility, I would recommend pasting the following code in the place where you are trying to play a video, and using a debugger to figure out where you are getting a nil value.

```
UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
UIViewController* rootViewController = [window rootViewController];
[self getVisibleViewControllerChild:rootViewController];
```

And here's the method we use, `getVisibleViewControllerChild`:

```
- (UIViewController*)getVisibleViewControllerChild:(UIViewController*)viewController {

UIViewController* visibleViewController = nil;

if(!viewController) {
return nil;
}

if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController*)viewController;
viewController = navigationController.visibleViewController;
}

while (visibleViewController == nil) {

if (viewController.modalViewController == nil) {
visibleViewController = viewController;
} else {

if ([viewController.modalViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)viewController.modalViewController;
viewController = navigationController.visibleViewController;
} else {
viewController = viewController.modalViewController;
}
}

}

return visibleViewController;
}
```

Hope this helps other people who get the similar problem.

Comment: Hi,do apple approve the apps that use adcolony sdk?

Comment: I've the same problem. I'm using UIAlertView, I don't know how to dismiss the UIAlertView before playing adcolony video. How to solve it? I've to wait for 2 seconds to let the UIalertView dismiss then play the video, otherwise:`Warning: Attempt to present <_UIModalItemsPresentingViewController: 0x1d0b09b0>  on <_UIModalItemAppViewController: 0x1d073750> which is already presenting <_UIModalItemsPresentingViewController: 0x1d072df0>`

Comment: [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:NO];  solved by it

Comment: [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:NO]; did not alone work for me on iOS 8 devices.  I had to then delay showing the ad a second while the dialog disappeared.